# ASP.NET Server error in '/' application - ashx handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, httphandler, ashx

I'm making a local CMS where I can create/edit/delete Posts, Tags, Authors and Roles, using *.ashx handlers. The Posts and Tags had been working fine, until I added functionality for authors and roles. Since adding those, whenever I tried to create/edit/delete a Post or Tag, I received the "Server error in '/' application: Resource cannot be found" error with, for example, Requested URL: /admin/post.ashx.

I found that it was most likely due to a copy/paste typo I made in web.config for removing and adding handlers, where I removed the Post and Tag handlers twice:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="PostHandler"/>
    <add name="PostHandler" type="PostHandler" verb ="POST" path="/admin/post.ashx"/>
    <remove name="TagHandler"/>
    <add name="TagHandler" type="TagHandler" verb ="POST" path="/admin/tag.ashx"/>
    <remove name="PostHandler"/>
    <add name="AccountHandler" type="AccountHandler" verb ="POST" path="/admin/account.ashx"/>
    <remove name="TagHandler"/>
    <add name="RoleHandler" type="RoleHandler" verb ="POST" path="/admin/role.ashx"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

The handler code now looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="PostHandler"/>
    <add name="PostHandler" type="PostHandler" verb ="POST" path="/admin/post.ashx"/>
    <remove name="TagHandler"/>
    <add name="TagHandler" type="TagHandler" verb ="POST" path="/admin/tag.ashx"/>
    <remove name="AccountHandler"/>
    <add name="AccountHandler" type="AccountHandler" verb ="POST" path="/admin/account.ashx"/>
    <remove name="RoleHandler"/>
    <add name="RoleHandler" type="RoleHandler" verb ="POST" path="/admin/role.ashx"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

However, having corrected the typos, I'm still receiving the same error for posts and tags only. I've tried rebuilding the solution, rebuilding website, reloading visual studio and clearing cache/browsing history, etc. in my browser, but I'm still having a problem creating/editing/deleting Posts and Tags. Roles and Accounts are fine.

I'm completely stumped - any ideas on what I need to do to rectify this?

Comment: So I read thru your question really fast and didn't catch that you had corrected the typos, please include what that handler block looks like now

Comment: @curtisk That's done.

Comment: Why are you registering these in the config file? The whole idea with `.ashx` handlers are that they will handle any requests to their specific url. No need to mention them in `web.config`...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean the solution before rebuilding it.

If that doesn't work too, try changing the key names like MyTagHandler for TagHandler.

Comment: He said he already corrected that, his example was the "before" version, I did the  same thing and answered like you before I read the question again

Comment: @curtisk OK i didn't expect that, i answered for the first version of the question :)

Comment: @er-han I've edited my post to include the "after" version for clarity.

Comment: @duney did you try cleaning the solution?